# MySql queries getting thread_killed

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, shared-hosting

I brought the shared server hosting in hostgator.in. It was fine before a week but now most of the my msql queries getting killed thread. I saw that at the file named "killed_mysql_queries.log".

Because of that I also getting this error- An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.

Here is what exact error I am getting in file killed_mysql_queries.log- http://prntscr.com/9tqka4

Please let me know what I supposed to do?

Comment: do you use nginx with php-fpm ?

Comment: Thanks for response. NO. its a wordpress website running on hostgator shared hosting service

Comment: have you change something - instaal wp or so on the same server where is the DB installed. so it it possible that mysql or wp use to much memory

Comment: i dont knw. this is multiple domain hosting. this may help u its my db dasboard image http://prntscr.com/9trmgp